# Most efficient way to implement mouse smoothing

Tags: javascript, algorithm, opengl, opengl-es

I'm finishing up a drawing application that uses OpenGL ES 2.0 (WebGL) and JS. Things work pretty well unless I draw with very quick movements. See the image below:

[image: Faceted loop]

This loop was drawn with a smooth motion, but because JS was only able to get mouse readings at specific locations, the result is faceted. This happens to a certain degree in Photoshop if you have mouse smoothing turned off, though obviously much less because PS has the ability to poll at a much higher rate.

So, I would like to implement some mouse smoothing, but I'm concerned about making sure it's very efficient so that it doesn't bog down the actual pixel drawing operations. I was originally thinking about using the mouse locations that JS is able to grab to generate splines and interpolate between readings to give a smoother result. I'm not sure if this is the best approach, though. If it is, how do I make sure I sample the correct locations on the intermediate spline? Most of the spline equations I've found don't have uniformly-distributed values for `t = [0, 1]`.

Any help/guidance/advice would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catmull-Rom might be a good one to try, if you haven't already.

http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/catmull/

I'd pick a minimum segment length and divide up segments that are over that into 1+segmentLength/minSegmentLength sub-segments.

Comment: I actually played around a bit with Catmull-Rom splines for this, but I couldn't get the intervals to work well. The issue is that you can control t in the equation to get a new point, but a value of 0.5 for t is not necessarily (or even typically) halfway between the two end points. Unless I'm missing something, I guess I would have to do a binary search to move my t the proper distance along the spline for each sub-segment?

Comment: A point for t=0.5 should be halfway _on the path_ between two points. That is not necessarily anywhere near halfway between the points, but this is perfectly normal. Points on a spline are never evenly spaced on any spline, except by accident. Though you can try to minimize the effect on splines that have tangents as parameters, but this comes at the expense of a significantly different curve form. For interpolating some hand-drawn sketch, simple Catmull-Rom is normally totally sufficient. It is well-known, well-tested, and something that "just works".

Comment: @Damon The point when t=0.5 will not be halfway on the path between two points. The t parameter does not correlate to arc length at all. In order to select proper t values such that your interpolation points are evenly spaced along the curve you must re-parametrize using another function. This re-parametrization is not exactly cheap, so I was looking for alternatives. Having said that, I think I can estimate an acceptable stepping for t and throw out excess values if it's too small. I'll mark this accepted--thanks for the discussion guys.